# JS, how to append array in FormData?

Tags: javascript, arrays, append, form-data

i hope append array in js FormData.

like this,

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("key", new Array(["a","b","c"]));
console.log(fd.get("key"));
```

the result is,

```
a,b,c
```

result type is 'String'...

i want to parse "aa" array in java(JSONArray).

please help me.

Comment: _"the result is `a,b,c`"_  that's because `FormData` only accepts string or `Blob` values (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#append()_Parameters) so the array is being converted to a string. It's unclear what you want the value to actually be

Answer (score 8):

You need to stringify your data first:

```
fd.append("key", JSON.stringify(["a","b","c"]));
```

And then when you want to retrieve the data parse it back into an array. This can be done manually using `JSON.parse()`, or, if you're using express, can be done for you by using the JSON/urlencoded body-parser middleware.

---

**Explanation**:

When you use `.append()`, the data passed as a second argument will be converted into a string. In the case of an array, the `.toString()` method gets called which joins the elements inside your array by a comma

```
a,b,c
```

This isn't good as this cannot be parsed back into the array easily, especially when you have complex arrays such as an array of objects or a multi-dimensional array.

However, as [@Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) pointed out, you can manage this by using `JSON.stringify` on your input array. This way, you're providing a JSON string, which can easily be parsed back into data using `JSON.parse()`

```
"[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]" // <-- can be parsed into an array using JSON.parse()
```

See working example below:

```js
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("key", JSON.stringify(["a","b","c"]));

var str_arr = fd.get("key");
console.log(str_arr); // string format
console.log(JSON.parse(str_arr)); // array format
```

Comment: Why not use `JSON.stringify()` on the value when appending it instead of attempting to build your own JSON formatter

Comment: @Phil good point actually! I've updated my answer to use this instead. thanks

Comment: Anyone new coming here for reference, `fd.append("key", JSON.stringify(new Array(["a","b","c"])));` can be simply eased to `fd.append("key", JSON.stringify(["a","b","c"]));`. No need to add `new Array` to an existing array of items.

Comment: @bubble-cord good point, I must’ve kept it from the OP’s question. I’ve updated it to remove the array constructor

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to append an array to formdata.

**Sample Array**

const array = [
{
value: 2,
label: 'test'
},
{
value: 2,
label: 'test'
},
]

```
for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
  data.append(`array[${index}][value]`, array[index].value);
  data.append(`array[${index}][label]`, array[index].label);
}
```