# How to send multiplechoicesfield in post request - Postman

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, postman

I use `django-multiselectfield` package in my project and based on its [docs](https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield) I use `MultipleChoiceField` in my serializer:

```
class InsCatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   levels = fields.MultipleChoiceField(choices=LEVEL)
```

when I send a request with raw JSON in postman that works fine

```
"levels": ["INTERMEDIATE", "ADVANCED"]
```

But I need to use form data because I have files and images in my request!

I try this way:

```
levels:INTERMEDIATE
levels:ADVANCED
```

but just saved the last element ( ADVANCED in this example )

any suggestion to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Json Array and Form data can't work together. Please stringify your array or don't use form data at all.

Read more: [JS, how to append array in FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735223/js-how-to-append-array-in-formdata)