# Append array of objects through form data not working as I expecte

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multipartform-data, form-data

I am trying to append an array of objects through form data. But it's not working as I expected.
This is my Array ob object.

```
const children = [{title:"MacBook",type:"LapTop"},{title:"MSI",type:"LapTop"}]
```

This is how I append my data to formData.

```
const formData = new FormData();
children.forEach(item => {
            formData.append('children[]', item)
        });
```

But this is how the final output.
[image]

I tried this using `JSON.stringify()` to serialize.But it's not working. anyone can help me with this..?

What I expect to like this:
[image]

Comment: What is your expected result and what is wrong with the output you're getting? Have you seen: [JS, how to append array in FormData?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53735223)

Comment: share a snack with your code and let us know what's your expected output

Comment: @Nick Parsons  I update my question. Can you help me now..?

Comment: @Salwa A. Soliman  I update my question. Can you help me now..?